# Bayesian Network, Starship Enterprise problem

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, bayesian-network

The starship Enterprise is under re from the Borg and Data the android is trying to save it. He knows
that if the ship is close to the Borg vessel and the power is high, he will hit the Borg with probability
90%. If the Enterprise is close but the power is low, the probability drops to 70%. If the Enterprise
is far and the battery is high, the chances of a successful hit are 50%. If the Enterprise is far and
the battery is low, the chance of success is only 10%. Data has a sensor which tells him whether the
Enterprise is far or close, but this sensor sometimes malfunctions: it indicates the correct distance only
with probability 80%.

So, some of the probabilities below are given
$$p(Hit|Distance,\,Power) $$
Also, we know 
$$p(Distance) = .8$$

How do I draw the Bayesian Network for this? Also, if power is low and Enterprise is close is $p(Hit|Distance,\,Power) = .7 $ ?

Comment: This setup seems incomplete. What are you trying to infer? $p(Hit|Distance, Power)$? What is Data's decision set?

Comment: @ssdecontrol wrote "What are you trying to infer?" The OP is trying to infer the solution to homework or take-home exam problem.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I inferred as much

Comment: There are various things that I don't get, The problem gives me $p(Hit|Distance,\, Power)$ for 4 cases. Now, let's say I have sensor and $p(Sensor works correctly)=.8$. So, should my Bayes net contain $Sensor$ as a node and put $Distance$ as a node below? If so, how do I calculate $p(Distance|Sensor)$.  basically how to calculate the joint distribution $p(Distance, Sensor)$ for this toy problem?